# Cargo dependency conflict with multiple git submodules

Tags: rust, git-submodules, rust-cargo

We have a Rust Cargo project under Git that we have divided into multiple submodules each under their own git repo to allow controlled access by different teams, some external. Some teams will just work on one sub-module. Here is a simplified structure:

```
Project
   ---Module 1
   ---Sub-Module 1
   ---Sub-Module 2
   ---Sub-Module 3
```

`Module 1` has a dependency on all 3 sub-modules; and `Sub-Module 1` and `Sub-Module 2` also have dependencies on `Sub-Module 3`.

The advantage of using sub-modules is that changes can be made to `Module 1` and the sub-modules together and compiled togeher, as opposed to just keeping the sub-modules as separate repos and developing them separately.

Since `Sub-Module 1` and `Sub-Module 2` are independent repos, they have no direct knowledge of `Sub-Module 3` and therefore must include it via the git repo.

`Module 1` is including `Sub-Module 3` as a direct path. This causes the conflict in Cargo as Module 1 has two versions of `Sub-Module 3` - one direct dependency and one through `Sub-Module 1` / `Sub-Module 2`.

Solution A would be to include `Sub-Module 3` into `Module 1` via the git repo (instead of via a direct path), but this defeats the object of having it as a submodule as any coding changes to `Sub-Module 3` would have to be coded, committed and pushed to the repo before `Module 1` can see them.

Solution B would be to add `Sub-Module 3` in itself as a sub-module to `Sub-Module 1` and `Sub-Module 2` and this would then negate the need to define the depenency via the git repo. But then `Sub-Module 3` would appear twice in the Project and this might get confusing. Also, we have not tested this but suspect that Cargo would still have the same conflict as it will still have two versions of `Sub-Module 3`.

This is the type of error being produced by Cargo:

```
    = note: expected struct sub_module_3::ExampleStruct
               found struct ExampleStruct
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `sub_module_3` are being used?
```

Any advice on how to solve this much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't have time to double-check and test, but this is probably possible with an [override](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html). Try out the example like so: `[patch.'https://github.com/example/baz']
baz = { git = 'https://github.com/example/patched-baz', branch = 'my-branch' }`.

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed look like the solution. Will take a look and let you know if not. Thank you for the quick response - much appreciated, just could not find the answer via Google - it needed a human with experience!

Comment: @kmdreko This is absolutely the correct solution. Changed all dependencies to the git repos and then patched them once at the workspace level so use local submodule paths. Thank you again! (If you'd like to post the answer, will mark it as correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To normalize the dependency graph where some crates are accessing each other by version or repository and others are accessing the same crates by path, you need to [override](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html) the nested dependencies with a `[patch]` section in your Cargo.toml:

```toml
[patch.'https://github.com/sub-module-3'] # sub-module-1 and sub-module-2 use this dependency
sub-module-3 = { path '../sub-module-3' } # they should instead use the local path
```

This can either be done just for the module-1 crate or at the workspace root if you want to have the patches applied for developing the sub-modules.